# Помогите, пожалуйста, с установкой патча для ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Я пишу программу на питоне, которая сможет открывать файлы .braw, брать скриншот и узнавать данные о видео. Проблема заключалась в том, что, как мне казалось, нет готовых решений. Так вот, я наткнулся на патчи для ffmpeg, но я искренне не понимаю, как их установить
ссылка на патч: https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20191214115705.25497-1-onemda@gmail.com/#49268

подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо сделать, а в идеале по шагово, потому что я пенек и хлебушек.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Comment: вообще не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

1. Средствами git:

> git apply yourfile.diff

2. средствами patch http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/patch.1.html

Comment: Я честно не понимаю, что нужно сделать + у меня windows